# Proof Verification of Intermediate Value Theorem in topology textbook

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

**Intermediate Value Theorem**:
If $f:[a,b]_{\mathcal{U}_{[a,b]}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{U}}$ is continuous and if c is any real number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then there exists a number $z \in (a,b)$ such that $f(z) = c$.

**Remark**: $\mathcal{U}$ indicates the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{U}_{[a,b]}$ is the subspace topology on A.

**Proof**:
Suppose that $\forall x \in (a,b)$, $f(x) \neq c$. Since $f$ is continuous, then $Im(f)$ is connected.
Consider the following disjoint sets: $$A = (-\infty,c) \cap Im(f) \qquad and \qquad (c,+\infty) \cap Im(f)$$
Since $(-\infty,c)$ and $(c,+\infty)$ are both $\mathcal{U}$-open, therefore $A$ and $B$ are $\mathcal{U}_{Im(f)}$-open.
Observe that $f(x) \neq c$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, i.e., $c \notin Im(f)$. It follows that $A \amalg B = Im(f)$. So by definition $Im(f)$ is disconnected, contradiction.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: What the hell is going on with this $\mathcal{U}$ thing? Is this some nonstandard analysis? Or does it stand just for "usual topology"? If the latter, you can just not use it, $\Bbb R$ is always understood as having the usual topology unless otherwise specified

Comment: This is a valid proof and imo this is the best and slickest proof. The connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ are precisely the intervals, therefore the continuous image of an interval must be an interval

Comment: Thank you for checking my proof.